# Git submodule inside of a submodule (nested submodules)

Tags: git, git-submodules

Is it possible for a git submodule to be made of several other git submodules, and the super git repo to fetch the contents for each submodule?

I have tried to do this using the obvious/naive approach of creating a git repo holding several submodules.

Then adding this git repo to another git repo as a submodule.

Then attempting to pull from the root directory of the super git repo by `git submodule init` and then `git submodule update`.  But this fails to fetch the sub-submodules.

Comment: I suggest that you use TortoiseGit -- use it in your root and then ask it to update all submodules with Initialize, Recursive, Force checked !

Answer (score 267, accepted):

As mentioned in [Retrospectively add --recursive to a git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251940/retrospectively-add-recursive-to-a-git-repo/4261001)

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

should work.

Comment: This worked for me. Note that I erroneously thought that `git submodule init; git submodule update --recursive` was synonymous with the above, but it is not.

Comment: +1 I like this much better than what I was using:  git submodule foreach git submodule init ... then git submodule update --recursive

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. No erros, no messages, nothing.

Comment: How do you update theses fully nested repos though? When I pass in the `--init` flag, the submodules, within one of my submodules, just get initialized to old versions, not the most current ones.

Comment: I do `git submodule foreach git pull origin master`, and it works partially: submodules are updated, but sometimes the `HEAD` gets detached and for submodules within submodules, I can't commit my direct submodule's changes because it has "modified content" not "new commits" (since its own submodules have "new commits" and are updated).

Comment: You can also add `--remote` to this command if you'd like to fetch from a specific branch: 
`git submodule update --init --recursive --remote`

Answer (score 60):

As [Sridhar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55246/sridhar-ratnakumar) comments below, from Git1.6.5+, **`git clone --recursive`** is now the official alternative, described in:

- "[`git clone --submodule`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796927/git-clone-submodule)"
- "[Retrospectively add `--recursive` to a git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251940/retrospectively-add-recursive-to-a-git-repo/4261001#4261001)"
  (with the **`alias $ git config --global alias.cloner = 'clone --recursive'`**, which avoids shadowing the normal `git clone` command)

[inamiy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/666371/inamiy) correctly [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6562038/6309) the `git submodule update --init --recursive` command, introduced in [commit b13fd5c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b13fd5c1a2bd450cdf7b853e0c4861f361882a18), again in git1.6.5, by [Johan Herland (`jherland`)](https://github.com/jherland).

And [IceFire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2573127/icefire) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535524/git-submodule-inside-of-a-submodule-nested-submodules/1535541?noredirect=1#comment78886758_1535541):

> If you would like to checkout only one submodule of a submodule, then
>   `git submodule update --init <submoduleName>` is the way to go.

---

(older original answer)

According to the [manual page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)

```
 git submodule update --recursive
```

should update any nested submodules. But the init part may not be recursive.

Depending on your version of Git, you could fall back to a more "scripting" approach, with this article [Recursively Updating Git Submodules](http://gaarai.com/2009/09/16/recursively-updating-git-submodules/) which allows for recursive init and update:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Cwd;

init_and_update();

exit;

sub init_and_update
{
    my $start_path = cwd();

    my %paths;
    my $updated;

    do
    {
        my $data = `find . -name '.gitmodules'`;
        chomp($data);

        $data =~ s/\/\.gitmodules//g;

        foreach my $path (split(/\n/, $data))
        {
            $paths{$path} = '' if($paths{$path} eq '');
        }

        $updated = 0;

        foreach my $path (sort keys %paths)
        {
            if($paths{$path} eq '')
            {
                chdir($path);
                `git submodule init 2>&1`;
                `git submodule update 2>&1`;
                chdir($start_path);

                if($ARGV[0] eq '--remove-gitmodules')
                {
                    unlink("$path/.gitmodules");
                }

                $paths{$path} = 1;

                $updated++;
            }
        }
    } while($updated);
}
```

Comment: Is not `git clone --recursive` sufficient?

Comment: @Sridhar: it is, for cloning, as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796927/git-clone-submodule and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251940/retrospectively-add-recursive-to-a-git-repo/4261001#4261001, from Git1.6.5 and later. I have edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Note: If you would like to checkout only one submodule of a submodule, then `git submodule update --init <submoduleName>` is the way to go; I got here when searching for this answer

Comment: @IceFire Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.