# How do I "git clone" a repo, including its submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules

How do I clone a git repository so that it also clones its submodules?

Running `git clone $REPO_URL` merely creates empty submodule directories.

Comment: @LiamCrowley , the parent (hosting, containing) repo might depend on a particular version of the submodule for a variety of reasons. For example, the maintainers of the host repo might not be ready to deal with updates just yet.

Comment: if your repo already exists then you do git submodule init then git submodule update --init potentially with the --remote flag too e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74999430/1601580

Comment: for ref, do `git clone --recurse-submodules --remote-submodules <repo-URL>`

Answer (score 3758, accepted):

With version 2.13 of Git and later, `--recurse-submodules` can be used instead of `--recursive`:

```
git clone --recurse-submodules -j8 git://github.com/foo/bar.git
cd bar
```

<sup>Editor’s note: `-j8` is an optional performance optimization that became available in version 2.8, and fetches up to 8 submodules at a time in parallel — see `man git-clone`.</sup>

With version 1.9 of Git up until version 2.12 (`-j` flag only available in version 2.8+):

```
git clone --recursive -j8 git://github.com/foo/bar.git
cd bar
```

With version 1.6.5 of Git and later, you can use:

```
git clone --recursive git://github.com/foo/bar.git
cd bar
```

For already cloned repos, or older Git versions, use:

```
git clone git://github.com/foo/bar.git
cd bar
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Comment: Is there any way to specify this behavior as default in your git repository, so that less-informed cloners will automatically get an initialized submodule?

Comment: @NHDaly Sadly, no. (Not that I know of, at least.)

Comment: And logically thinking git clone --recursive will also populate any submodules of a submodule, right?

Comment: @NHDaly it seems not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251940/retrospectively-add-recursive-to-a-git-repo

Comment: you may want to consider git subtree https://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/ It solves the problem in @NHDaly comment

Comment: @NHDaly sure, just add this into your `~/.gitconfig` under the `[alias]` section:  `cloner = clone --recursive`

Comment: @slf While that’s helpful, it doesn’t answer @NHDaly’s question. `.gitconfig` settings are global, not just for a single repository.

Comment: @mathius-bynens ah you are correct sir. I misread the question.

Comment: After doing either of these, it's wise to switch sources to the master branch (or any branch) since your repo will be sort of headless. From the top level repo -- ```git submodule foreach git checkout master```

Comment: @toszter: is it so wise? What if the holding repo needs a version of a submodule that is *not* `master`?

Comment: @Gauthier - Thank you... if it's _any branch_ other than master, as mentioned, substitute `master` with your preferred branch name _other_ than `master`.

Comment: @toszter Even so, the correct commit is not necessarily at the tip of the branch.

Comment: you can use `git submodule update --depth 10 --recursive --init` to shallow the repo

Comment: This doesn't work with git 2.7, but worked with git 2.9

Comment: Thanks! I had forgotten to actually retrieve the submodule dependency contents with `git submodule update --init --recursive` before running `sh -c 'cd cmd/ios7crypt && go install'`

Comment: I did `git submodule update --init --recursive` but all the submodules are in dechated head state, I have to go into each submodule and checkout master. Does anybody know why?

Comment: I have git 1.9.1 and `git clone --recursive -j8 git@bitbucket.org:repoToClone` does not work. It tells me `error: unknown switch `j' `

If I remove the `-j8` it works smoothly

Comment: As it seems, the flag name was updated to `--recurse-submodules`

Comment: I think I come back to this answer once a month... Why don't git just ask upon cloning if it should also download the submodules?

Comment: I suppose the -j8 option is not available for already clone repos?

Comment: If the repos is not public and a token/authentication is needed, this cmd will ask you to type in again and again the access token/ or user_password for every submodule. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Also to make clear (since I wanted to know and couldn't find an answer except by looking at the source), the git clone `--recursive` and `--recurse-submodules` options behave identically. They result in a call to the same function.

Comment: Why isn't recursive cloning the default option?

Comment: what happens if you do them in reverse?

Comment: why is your answer better than `git clone --recurse-submodules --remote-submodules <repo-URL>`?

Comment: @weefwefwqg3 my solution to that is to talk to any remote via ssh and ask git to rewrite such https urls to ssh using the `url.xyz.insteadOf` config. For my client that uses bitbucket, this looks like the following:
`git config --global url."git@bitbucket.org:".insteadOf "https://bitbucket.org/"`
If you only want to do it for a specific org: 
`git config --global url."git@bitbucket.org:that-org/".insteadOf "https://bitbucket.org/that-org/"`

Answer (score 646):

You have to do two things before a submodule will be filled:

```
git submodule init 
git submodule update
```

Comment: I was afraid of that... it doesn't make any sense since you're checking out a partial project in that case.  I understand that the submodule updates aren't automatic, but why isn't the bound version automatically checked out??  Is there any way to force it?  I have a project with 3-levels of submodules and it seems absurd to have to traverse that far just to do a checkout.

Comment: Please read the `git-submodule(1)` man page (http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html). You'll find out that `git submodule update` supports a nice parameter called `--recursive`.

Comment: Why not just do both of them in one command? `git submodule update --init` (Also see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796927/git-clone-submodule/4438292#4438292)).

Comment: I think its better to answer the question with these two commands. Its explains better how to accomplish the task.

Comment: @MathiasBynens A machine that I just logged into only has git 1.5.5.6, which apparently does not support the shortened instruction, but does support it as two commands.

Comment: @MathiasBynens I think you misunderstood. ``git submodule update --init`` must be expanded to ``git submodule init; git submodule update`` in 1.5.5.6.

Comment: After I do this, then if I cd into the submodule directory and to `git pull` it says its head is detached and I can't do `git pull` in it to update, any way to fix this?

Comment: what happens if you do them in reverse?

Comment: why not `git submodule update --init --recursive`

Comment: Because when that answer was made (2010) that was not an option.

Answer (score 357):

Git 2.23 (Q3 2019): if you want to clone *and* update the submodules to their latest revision:

```
git clone --recurse-submodules --remote-submodules <repo-URL>
```

If you just want to clone them at their recorded SHA1:

```
git clone --recurse-submodules <repo-URL>
```

See below.

Note that Git 2.29 (Q4 2020) brings a significant optimization around submodule handling.

See [commit a462bee](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a462bee5d5b52c9778a9df600494fbd87f3c5fb9) (06 Sep 2020) by [Orgad Shaneh (`orgads`)](https://github.com/orgads).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 2ce9d4e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2ce9d4e5c7186e15f2e2f7be06a9db52b5e61bde), 18 Sep 2020)</sup>

> ### [`submodule`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a462bee5d5b52c9778a9df600494fbd87f3c5fb9): suppress checking for file name and ref ambiguity for object ids
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Orgad Shaneh</sup>

> The argv argument of `collect_changed_submodules()` contains only object ids (the objects references of all the refs).
>
> Notify `setup_revisions()` that the input is not filenames by passing `assume_dashdash,` so it can avoid redundant stat for each ref.
>
> Also suppress `refname_ambiguity` flag to avoid filesystem lookups for each object. Similar logic can be found in cat-file, pack-objects and more.
>
> **This change reduces the time** for [`git fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a462bee5d5b52c9778a9df600494fbd87f3c5fb9/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup> in my repo **from 25s to 6s**.

---

Original answer 2010

As [joschi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49505/joschi) mentions in the comments, **[`git submodule`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)** now supports the `--recursive` option (Git1.6.5 and more).

> If `--recursive` is specified, this command will recurse into the registered submodules, and update any nested submodules within.

See [Working with git submodules recursively](http://cemerick.com/2009/09/28/working-with-git-submodules-recursively/) for the init part.
See **[`git submodule` explained](http://longair.net/blog/2010/06/02/git-submodules-explained/)** for more.

> With version 1.6.5 of git and later, you can do this automatically by cloning the super-project with the `–-recursive` option:
>
> ```
> git clone --recursive git://github.com/mysociety/whatdotheyknow.git
> ```

---

Update 2016, with git 2.8: see "[How to speed up / parallelize downloads of git submodules using `git clone --recursive`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34762036/6309)"

You can initiate fetching the submodule using multiple threads, in parallel.
For instances:

```
git fetch --recurse-submodules -j2
```

---

Even better, with Git 2.23 (Q3 2019), you can clone and checkout the submodule to their tracking branch in one command!

See [commit 4c69101](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4c6910163ab59f334becca39f5a83d3b7a622df4) (19 May 2019) by [Ben Avison (`bavison`)](https://github.com/bavison).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9476094](https://github.com/git/git/commit/94760948f17e1902e071172677e0615da6e03d90), 17 Jun 2019)</sup>

> ### `clone`: add `--remote-submodules` flag

> When using `git clone --recurse-submodules` there was previously no way to pass a `--remote` switch to the implicit `git submodule update` command for any use case where you want the submodules to be checked out on their remote-tracking branch rather than with the SHA-1 recorded in the superproject.
>
> This patch rectifies this situation.
> It actually passes `--no-fetch` to `git submodule update` as well on the grounds the submodule has only just been cloned, so fetching from the remote again only serves to slow things down.

That means:

> ```
> --[no-]remote-submodules:
> ```
>
> All submodules which are cloned will use the status of the submodule’s remote-tracking branch to update the submodule, rather than the superproject’s recorded SHA-1. Equivalent to passing `--remote` to `git submodule update`.

---

[jhu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9009630/jhu) notes in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796927/how-do-i-git-clone-a-repo-including-its-submodules/3797061#comment135631560_3797061):

> If you want to use `git clone --recurse-submodules --remote-submodules <repo-URL>` to clone and update to the latest version, your submodules must either:
>
> 1. have a branch `master`, assumed by git when running the above, or
> 2. record a valid branch name in the `.gitmodules` of the cloned repo. >
>    Otherwise you will get an error about a missing head, and cloning will fail.
>    So if you have a submodule without branch `master`, say submodule sub with branch `main`, run in the root dir of the cloned repo `git config -f .gitmodules submodule.sub.branch main` and push your changes to the remote.

Comment: So it took Git 14 years to start adding proper support for submodules, huh. Thanks for the update!
What if I already have a clone of the main repo without submodules and without a recorded SHA1, and I want to pull in the latest version of each submodule. Is it doable?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe If that cloned repository has submodules, it has "recorded SHA1". And a `git submodule update --init --recursive --remote` should update them to the latest commit of their respective branch. (ex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56981834/6309)

Comment: Let me clarify with an example: I have a template project on Github that uses submodules, and I even commited specific revisions of the submodules into this template repo. But when I create a new project out of this repo, none of the commands you listed (neither `clone --recurse-submodules --remote-submodules` nor `submodule update --init --recursive --remote`) let me actually fetch the subrepos. All I get is a .gitmodules file, and I couldn't find any way to init the subrepos other than manually cloning them one by one. I'd like to at least have a script to do it with `submodule foreach`...

Comment: If you know a solution, I'd ask a separate question that you could answer. Here's the test repo that I can't find any way to init other than by hand: https://github.com/VioletGiraffe/TEST

Comment: @VioletGiraffe That is because you have added and committed the .gitmodules but not the gitlink (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309, special entries in the index: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309) Here is a repository which does have the proper gitlink registered: https://github.com/tiagomazzutti/antlr4dart

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Solution: clone your repo, delete the .gitmodules, add, and commit. Then add the submodules again: `git submodule add cpputils https://github.com/VioletGiraffe/cpputils.git` and `git submodule add cpp-template-utils https://github.com/VioletGiraffe/cpp-template-utils`. Add, commit and push. You will then see your submodules, and can clone back that repository *with* said submodules.

Comment: Right, I understand that, and it works for any "normal" repo you create from scratch. I think we're looking at a Github bug with regards to handling subrepos in project templates specifically, because the original template repo has gitlinks as well, but not the new project created from this template. P. S. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: @VioletGiraffe You could still update that project template with the process I mentioned. But yes, that looks like a bug on GitHub side. That would be interesting to illustrate/detail that in a separate question. I will answer it when I go back from work.

Comment: What exactly does `--remote-submodules`? Does it pull for each submodule the latest commit, and then update the reference in the superproject?

Comment: @AvivCohn It does pull for each submodule the latest commit of their associated branch (`master/main` by default). To my understanding, you still need to add and commit in the parent repo, in order to record the new submodules tree SHA.

Comment: isn't your git clone cmd missing the repo url?

Comment: If you want to use `git clone --recurse-submodules --remote-submodules <repo-URL>` to clone and update to the latest version, your submodules *must* either 1. have a branch `master`, *assumed* by git when running the above, or 2. record a valid branch name in the `.gitmodules` of the cloned repo. Otherwise you will get an error about a missing head, and cloning will fail. So if you have a submodule without branch `master`, say submodule `sub` with branch `main`, run in the root dir of the cloned repo `git config -f .gitmodules submodule.sub.branch main ` and push your changes to the remote.

Comment: @jhu Good point, thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: This answer is the closest one to the question post.

Answer (score 170):

You can use this command to clone your repo with all the submodules:

```
git clone --recursive YOUR-GIT-REPO-URL
```

Or if you have already cloned the project, you can use:

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Comment: On git version 2.24.3 the above command gives me the error: 

error: Server does not allow request for unadvertised object e635630d55682951eb2da35630d5da15b6cc
Fetched in submodule path 'ui-library', but it did not contain e635630d55682951eb2da35630d5da15b6cc. Direct fetching of that commit failed.

Comment: ran the second option, nothing happens

Comment: what happens if you do them in reverse?

Answer (score 123):

### [Quick Answer]

After cloning the parent repo (including some submodule repos), do the following:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Comment: or --remote if you want the right branch

Answer (score 47):

Use this command to clone repo with all submodules

```
git clone --recurse-submodules git@gitlab.staging-host.com:yourproject
```

To update code for all submodules

```
git submodule update --recursive --remote
```

Comment: --remote also makes sure the right branch from remote is used. Right?

Answer (score 40):

If your submodule was added in a branch be sure to include it in your clone command...

```
git clone -b <branch_name> --recursive <remote> <directory>
```

Comment: This was more like what I was looking for... but the submodules list their branch as 'detached'.  :(

Answer (score 35):

Try this:

```
git clone --recurse-submodules
```

It automatically pulls in the submodule data assuming you have already added the submodules to the parent project.

Comment: Note that `--recurse-submodules` and `--recursive` are [equivalent aliases](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html).

Comment: @SuperUberDuper in that case you can do `git submodule update --init --recursive` as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4438292/854076)

Answer (score 28):

I think you can go with 3 steps:

```
git clone
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Answer (score 25):

You can use the `--recursive` flag when cloning a repository. This parameter forces git to clone all defined submodules in the repository.

```
git clone --recursive git@repo.org:your_repo.git
```

After cloning, sometimes submodules branches may be changed, so run this command after it:

```bash
git submodule foreach "git checkout master"
```

Comment: + 1 foreach but not enough details. see this for a more detailed answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74988223/why-do-i-need-to-add-the-remote-to-gits-submodule-when-i-specify-the-branch/74999399#74999399

Comment: The `checkout` done here switches from a snapshot (detached head) to a working branch. And, say you have some submodules where the branch you want to work with is `master`, and some submodules where the branch you want to work with is `main`. (This is quite common now, since `master` used to be the default, but now it is typically `main`.) Then you can check out a working branch of *all* submodules by running `git submodule foreach --recursive "git checkout master || git checkout main" `

Answer (score 22):

*late answer*

```
// git CLONE INCLUDE-SUBMODULES ADDRESS DESTINATION-DIRECTORY
git clone --recursive https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/USERNAME/REPO.git DESTINATION_DIR
```

As I just spent a whole hour fiddling around with a friend: Even if you have Admin rights on BitBucket, always clone the ORIGINAL repository and use the password of the one who owns the repo. Annoying to find out that you ran into this minetrap :P

Comment: That's exactly what I'm dealing with.  So, are you saying that anyone who needs to develop on a bitbucket repository that has submodules must use the repository creator's credentials?  Blech.

Comment: @jsleuth Seems so - it sucks BIG TIME... and I know it.

Comment: That sounds like a bug. Did you report it to Bitbucket?

Comment: @MathiasBynens Did you stumble upon this issue? It's one and a half years later and I actually don't know if this is still the case.

Comment: @kaiser No, I just stumbled upon your answer and was surprised.

Comment: This is the case only if you use HTTPS and the user is in the URL? The "right" way is to use the SSH auth with a private/public key pair, so the password would not be requested.

Comment: @kaiser This answer should really be deleted

Comment: It doesn't descriptively answer the OPs question, but details an unrelated bug in Bitbucket; which, incidentally, could just be shortened to "use SSH key authentication".

Comment: Still not resolved on Bitbucked. I'm using relative paths to submodules and as a trick I have to perform following steps:
`- git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:namespace/main-repo.git`
`- git submodule update --init --recursive`

Answer (score 21):

Try this for including submodules in git repository.

```
git clone -b <branch_name> --recursive <remote> <directory>
```

**or**

```
git clone --recurse-submodules
```

Answer (score 19):

Just do these in your project directory.

```
$ git submodule init
$ git submodule update
```

Comment: This is the right answer if you had already cloned your repo before.

Answer (score 12):

Submodules parallel fetch aims at reducing the time required to fetch a repositories and all of its related submodules by enabling the fetching of multiple repositories at once. This can be accomplished by using the new --jobs option, e.g.:

```
git fetch --recurse-submodules --jobs=4
```

According to Git team, this can substantially speed up updating repositories that contain many submodules. When using --recurse-submodules without the new --jobs option, Git will fetch submodules one by one.

Source: http://www.infoq.com/news/2016/03/git28-released

Answer (score 10):

If it is a new project simply you can do like this :

```
$ git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/chaconinc/YourProjectName
```

If it is already installed than :

```
$ cd YourProjectName (for the cases you are not at right directory) 
$ git submodule init
$ git submodule update
```

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem for a GitHub repository. My account was missing SSH Key. The process is

1. [Generate SSH Key](https://help.github.com/en/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)
2. [Adding a new SSH key to your GitHub account](https://help.github.com/en/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)

Then, you can clone the repository with submodules (`git clone --recursive YOUR-GIT-REPO-URL`)

or

Run `git submodule init` and `git submodule update` to fetch submodules in already cloned repository.

Comment: Yes, that is `Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.` error

Answer (score 8):

Try this.

```
git clone -b <branch_name> --recursive <remote> <directory>
```

If you have added the submodule in a branch make sure that you add it to the clone command.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to tell your git client to do all actions with `--recurse-submodules` then you can set this to your git config:

```
git config submodule.recurse true
```

See: https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-submodulerecurse

Comment: Unless this is for a newer git than I have, this does not appear to work (even with `--global`).

Comment: @Compholio `submodule.recurse` is documented in `man git config` in my `git version 2.39.2`

Comment: Yeah, the documentation that you have linked to says "clone and ls-files are not supported."  So, I do not believe that config option works to do this (it works for other things, just not clone).

Answer (score 1):

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

or maybe:

```
git stash -u
git pull origin master
git stash p
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend:

```bash
# - git submodule init initializes your local configuration file to track the submodules your repository uses, it just sets up the configuration so that you can use the git submodule update command to clone and update the submodules.
git submodule init
# - git submodule update --init initializes your local configuration file and clones the submodules for you, using the commit specified in the main repository.
#   note, command bellow will not pull the right branch -- even if it's in your .gitmodules file, for that you need remote. Likely because it looks at the origin (pointer to remote) in github for the available branches.
#   note, bellow pulls the submodules if you didn't specify them when cloning parent project, ref: https://youtu.be/wTGIDDg0tK8?t=119
git submodule update --init
```

if you have a specific branch for your submodules then change it to:

```bash
# - git submodule init initializes your local configuration file to track the submodules your repository uses, it just sets up the configuration so that you can use the git submodule update command to clone and update the submodules.
git submodule init

# - The --remote option tells Git to update the submodule to the commit specified in the upstream repository, rather than the commit specified in the main repository.
#git submodule update --init --remote
git submodule update --init --recursive --remote meta-dataset
```

For a full example that was testing:

```bash
# decided against this because it seems complicated

# - note to clone uutils with its submodule do (cmd not tested):
cd $HOME
git clone --recurse-submodules git@github.com:brando90/ultimate-utils.git

# - git submodules
cd $HOME/diversity-for-predictive-success-of-meta-learning

# - in case it's needed if the submodules bellow have branches your local project doesn't know about from the submodules upstream
git fetch

# -- first repo
# - adds the repo to the .gitmodule & clones the repo
git submodule add -f -b hdb --name meta-dataset git@github.com:brando90/meta-dataset.git meta-dataset/

# - ref for init then update: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796927/how-do-i-git-clone-a-repo-including-its-submodules/3796947#3796947
#git submodule init
#git submodule update

# - git submodule init initializes your local configuration file to track the submodules your repository uses, it just sets up the configuration so that you can use the git submodule update command to clone and update the submodules.
git submodule init
# - git submodule update --init initializes your local configuration file and clones the submodules for you, using the commit specified in the main repository.
#   note, command bellow will not pull the right branch -- even if it's in your .gitmodules file, for that you need remote. Likely because it looks at the origin (pointer to remote) in github for the available branches.
#   note, bellow pulls the submodules if you didn't specify them when cloning parent project, ref: https://youtu.be/wTGIDDg0tK8?t=119
git submodule update --init
# - The --remote option tells Git to update the submodule to the commit specified in the upstream repository, rather than the commit specified in the main repository.
#git submodule update --init --remote
git submodule update --init --recursive --remote meta-dataset

# - check we are using the right branch https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74998463/why-does-git-submodule-status-not-match-the-output-of-git-branch-of-my-submodule
git submodule status
cd meta-dataset
git branch  # should show hdb
cd ..

# pip install -r $HOME/meta-dataset/requirements.txt

# -- 2nd repo, simplified commands from above
git submodule add -f -b hdb --name pytorch-meta-dataset git@github.com:brando90/pytorch-meta-dataset.git pytorch-meta-dataset/

git submodule init
git submodule update --init --recursive --remote meta-dataset

# - check it's in specified branch
git submodule status
cd pytorch-meta-dataset
git branch  # should show hdb
cd ..

# pip install -r $HOME/pytorch-meta-dataset/requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If the submodules are [private submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74291357/4058484) you can use [credential store](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store) so that it also clones its  private submodules recursively.

```
USER=${GITHUB_ACTOR}
TOKEN=${{ secrets.JEKYLL_GITHUB_TOKEN }}

git config --global credential.helper store
echo "https://${USER}:${TOKEN}@github.com" > ~/.git-credentials

git clone --recurse-submodules -j8 git://github.com/foo/bar.git
cd bar
```

I use it to clone my submodules where the private one is in *5th level deep*. Please allow me to show you how it goes in action:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can copy clone url from github.

Then use:

```
git clone --recursive <url of clone copied above>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).