# Android: How to program changes to the standard android sms GUI

Tags: android, button, sms

I want to write an android app that changes the android standard message sms GUI giving it an extra send button. The one send button should be the usual one and the other should be the one that uses my application to send the message. How do I add this extra button in the android standard sms message GUI?  Anyone got an example code on how to do this?

Kind regards
Benjamin

Comment: "How do I add this extra button in the android standard sms message GUI?" -- are you building your own custom ROM?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335686/creating-a-custom-sms-mms-app-in-android-using-eclipse-and-github-why-so-man

Comment: in android, both codes are available (1) send sms (2) receive sms, so you can make your own sms application UI also. no need to change default sms app. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this you **Cannot** do for phones which are in the market. You will need to grab hold of the sources and come up with a custom ROM for users to flash.

However, as another option, you can build your own SMS application and let users install so. When users need to send a SMS, they will be asked whether we default/your app needs to be used. This way is a much cleaner approach and more reachable to users.