# Git clone --recursive is not listing the second level sub modules

Tags: git, recursion, clone, git-submodules

Cloning is not working properly for sub modules.
I have a Main git repo and added two repos as sub modules.Inside that submodule repo also i have some repos.

for Eg: Repo main ->submodule repo A(A having two repos as sub modules B and C).

(I executed all the necessary steps for adding and updating sub modules)

While cloning (git clone –recursive git @IP…:Repo main)

It is listing the submodule repo A.Then i did cd A:
But is not lising the Repos inside A(ie:B and C).I did git pull also after cloning.

But i am able to clone submodule repo B and C seperately.

Comment: Would cloning -- recursive A alone works? (ie would you see B and C included in A?)

Comment: While cloning repo A,submodule repo B and C is dispalying.Problem is i am not able to access the repos inside B and C.it is not listing the contents inside B and C

Comment: Is it a branch issue? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9610153/6309)

Comment: Can you try a submodule init and update within each submodule, just to see if the content does exist there? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3796947/6309)

Comment: I alredy did that.While clonig each repo (sub module repo also)seperately i am able to see all the sb module repos.

Comment: (I meant after cloning --recursive A, not after cloning B and C individually)

Comment: It is listing B and C while cloning A.