# Git does not update submodule when added using ssh path

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules

I am using git submodules. I have added submodule using ssh path as follows

```
.gitsubmodule

Name = MyProject
Url = git@bitbucket.org:MyAccount/MyProject.git
```

when I clone the repository, I don't get files in submodule directory but after using following command

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

I get all the submodule files.

Why is it so? How can I have all submodule files while clone the repository.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796927/how-to-git-clone-including-submodules

Comment: Yes but nobody tells actual solution. How can I update submodule while cloning the repo

Comment: If git 1.65+, you can do "git clone --recursive".