# Heroku and Leiningen: where did my files go?

Tags: heroku, github, clojure, leiningen

I have a Leiningen project that is dependent on another Leiningen project. Both are on Github. I cloned the project I am dependent on to the `checkouts` folder as a Git submodule, which works great in my development environment. I can use the classes from the dependency without even having to add it as a dependency in `projects.clj` (despite the fact that the [documentation](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/TUTORIAL.md#checkout-dependencies) says "If you have a project in checkouts without putting it in :dependencies then its source will be visible but its dependencies will not be found").

The main problem is that when I push the project to Heroku, the submodules are cloned automatically but there is no `checkouts` directory under `/app`. I guess that Heroku ignores `checkouts` for some reason.

Presumably I am doing this wrong and there's a right way for me to work in parallel with two Git repos, one of which is dependent on the other. The main issue for me is that I need to be able to deploy my app easily to Heroku. What is the standard way to deal with this situation?

**Update:** I also noticed that my `circle.yml` file, which is in the repo, is not in the `/app` directory. I'm totally confused about what exactly *is* in the `/app` directory and where the other stuff disappeared to.

Comment: Apparently it's nothing to do with `checkouts`. I moved the submodules to another directory and the behavior is still the same. I can see Heroku find and clone them, and yet they don't show up in `/app`.

Comment: This is how git works. You have to checkout the submodules after the clone, unless you specified the right options while cloning. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4438292/443992

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that heroku runs `lein with-profile production compile :all` which ignores checkout dependencies (see https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/1263).

A possible solution is to add `:checkout-deps-shares [:source-paths]` to your production profile. It's discouraged (according to heroku engineers you really should use an uberjar in production) but it should do the trick.