# Submodules don't sync with Git

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a library that relies on a number of other components. I've setup the main project and then added a number of submodules using git submodule add [url] [path].

The original project works fine. Each time I added a submodule it was cloned to the correct directory.

```
- Main project
-- Sub project [cloned correctly]
```

After that I pushed the original project to git. Now when I clone the main project, the sub project directories appear but they're empty.

```
- Main project
-- Sub project just empty folder
```

The .gitmodules is populated correctly but in the newly cloned main project, the .git/modules folder is empty.

No commands like git submodule sync or git submodule update work. However, if I manually re-add the modules they then appear in the directories without having to be re-downloaded. It says:

```
Reactivating local git directory for submodule
```

It's almost like git has the modules stored internally but doesn't add them to the file system.

What's the best practice for a situation like this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to \`git clone\` including submodules?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796927/how-to-git-clone-including-submodules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After cloning you need to:

```
git submodule init 
git submodule update
```

OR

clone the main repo and get submodules at the same time with:

```
git clone --recursive URL
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing

```
git submodule init
```

in the clones (before you can successfully run `git submodule update`)