# Possible to ignore certain submodules on Git checkout?

Tags: git, cross-platform, git-submodules

I am a big fan of Git submodules as they ensure the integrity of all 3rd party components in my projects.

However, these days I am dealing with a cross platform project with huge submodules. Some of them are only used by one platform. Is there a way to explicitly ignore certain submodules on checkout to optimize checkout time?

Comment: There's an opposite question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796927/how-to-git-clone-including-submodules

Comment: maybe this can help you? https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules#Issues-with-Submodules