# How clone qt source from git

Tags: git, qt, qt5.5, qt5.6

I need qt5.5 source code and I have seen this command:

```
git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git
```

Does this gives qt 5.5 version or qt 5.6 alpha version?

Is there a way to specify the version?

I saw a command:

```
git clone https://github.com/qtproject/qt5.git --branch v5.3.1**
```

Can I use a similar command to get qt 5.5 version?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course you can: just take a look at https://github.com/qtproject/qt5/branches and see the available branches. As you notice, your desired branch is called `5.5` - so use this in the git clone command. :)

`git clone https://github.com/qtproject/qt5.git --branch 5.5`

**Edit**: I just noticed, that the qt5 repository uses submodules to organize everything. In order to check them out as well (and not just having empty folders), please see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4438292/3380671) on how to checkout git submodules as well. :)

Comment: so i should use command as _git clone https://github.com/qtproject/qt5.git -b 5.5.1_ to get qt5 5.5.1 version code, right?

Comment: Thats right. And as mentioned in the referenced SO answer: to clone all the submodules as well, you can either do:

`git clone --recursive github.com/qtproject/qt5.git -b 5.5.1` if you have git version 1.6.5 or later.

Or you can do:
`git clone github.com/qtproject/qt5.git -b 5.5.1 && git submodule --init --recursive` if you have an older version.