# How to get the whole project from github based on the project URL?

Tags: git, github

In this particular case I am trying to get all files from the project

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/amqp

I am on Mac OS with git installed in the shell.  So I am trying to construct a git clone command based on [How to `git clone` including submodules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796927/how-to-git-clone-including-submodules) or some other similar links. Neither of my command works

Comment: I tried something like "git clone git://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/amqp.git" and some others

Comment: Use `git clone https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples.git`, navigate to the amqp example directory: `cd spring-integration-samples/basic/amqp`

Comment: Also seeing the git:// prior to your initial point in the comment section. Make sure that if you are not using ssh, you bring in the whole https:// angle or you may get some weird type of errors. Mainly because of the manner that github handles its address space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply clone it:

```
git clone https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples.git
```

Then, if it has submodules, get them using:

```
git submodule update --init
```

That's all.

You will have the whole project cloned on your machine. If you are interested in a specific subdirectory, simply explore it.

As far as I can see, the directory you are interested in is not a submodule of the project, so downloading the latter and visit the former is a good approach.

**EDIT**

As suggested in the comment by HBHB, you can do the same even using a single command:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples.git
```

Comment: NB: You can do this in one line by adding the `--recursive` flag: `git clone --recursive https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples.git`