# Add git submodule to branch of master repository

Tags: git, bitbucket

I want to know that is there any way to add git sub module to branch of master repository. So when i pull the branch code, the sub module should also be checked out?If possible please comment the steps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to \`git clone\` including submodules?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796927/how-to-git-clone-including-submodules)

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it's possible

#### but:

***`Submodule`*** is a **standalone** git project so the code will be checked out to a **new folder** under the root folder and it's not part of your master branch.

Your root folder will contain a submodule file and you will have to "int && update" it on every clone you make.

```
# Add the desired submodule ot your code base
git submodule add <url>
```

You must run two commands:

```
git submodule init
```

to initialize your local configuration file, and

```
git submodule update
```

to fetch all the data from that project and check out the appropriate commit listed in your superproject:

So the full script is this:

```
git submodule add <url>
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

---

[image]