# How do I add a private git submodule inside a public git repository?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-submodules

Both are hosted by GitLab. I want to add the private https://gitlab.com/rokejulianlockhart/s4a3h4.git to the public https://gitlab.com/rokejulianlockhart/rokejulianlockhart.git so that it appears as a directory to others and myself, but is solely accessible by myself.

I don't know where to start. All content on the internet appears to mention adding public git submodules to public repositories *so* that they can be edited simultaneously. However, I know that my desired configuration is possible per https://stackoverflow.com/a/37638473/9731176.