# How to `git clone` NOT-including submodules?

Tags: git, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

Scenario:

I need to work on a repo that has a submodule that is not necessary for me (in fact it causes error warnings and problems if I want to use GUIs like SourceTree because of access restrictions, etc.).

Question:

Is there a way to ignore submodules when cloning a remote repo?

Bonus:

I really want to know if this is possible with SourceTree?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`git clone` by itself does not pull submodules. You'd need to call `git submodule update --init` to do that... or use one of the variations found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796927/how-to-git-clone-including-submodules?rq=1).

To not clone submodules in SourceTree, in the `Clone` dialog, open `Advanced Options` and make sure `Recurse Submodules` is not checked.