# How can I hide some files from public but also version them in Github repository

Tags: git, github

I have a public repository on Github. In this repository I am sharing single file java applications structured as follows:

```
Root
  Folder1
    JavaApp1.java
    JavaApp2.java
  Folder2
    JavaApp3.java
```

In the other hand I am compiling these java applications within IntellijIdea. The problem is, I don't want to share `*.iml` files etc. in my public repository because I want to keep the repository as simple as possible.

In the other hand I want to store `*.iml` files etc. in Github for my own need. What can I achieve this requirement with Git?

Comment: Use a real build tool like Gradle or Maven, that anybody, whatever the IDE is, can run (outside of the IDE), or import in the IDE to have the IDE-specific files created automatically from the gradle build file or Maven POM.

Comment: My requirement will remain If I do so. I am also using Gradle with my projects. Let me explain, If I use Gradle, I would like to hide build.gradle file but also I would like to version it.

Comment: Why would you hide the build.gradle file. It's critical. It's how you build the project (defining dependencies, etc.). And it contains nothing secret. A repository is not simpler if it lacks the single file needed to build it. It's simpler if it contains it, and allows importing the project in any IDE.

Comment: I will only build the project; thus, I want to version build.gradle for myself.

Answer (score 2):

You would need two repos:

- one private for Root, including your `iml` files
- one public for your Java sources, referenced by the first one as a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule).

That way, you only clone you first private repo (and get your Root folder), and [that will clone the submodule as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4438292/6309) (in a "src" subfolder for instance)

```
cd /my/private/repo
git submodule add  -- /url/public/repo src
```