# Git:Submodules are not being pulled when cloning project

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I'm trying to clone on my repo from GitHub in another machine (Windows). I create a new directory and I ran the following commands in the new directory:

```
git init .
git remote add origin https://github.com/meme/myRepo.git
git pull origin master 
git push -u origin master
```

To make pull on the submodules I'm using I ran:

```
git pull --recurse-submodules
```

But nothing was showing in the submodules directory and then I ran:

```
git submodule update --recursive
```

But still nothing is showing on the submodules directory.

Any of you knows what I'm doing wrong or how can I pull the submodules files?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to \`git clone\` including submodules?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796927/how-to-git-clone-including-submodules)

Answer (score 32):

You can clone the submodule repos by executing this on your master repo folder

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

By the way, it's easier to clone the master repository with

```
git clone https://github.com/meme/myRepo.git .
```

(This will clone the repository inside the current folder)

You can also do it all in a single step:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/meme/myRepo.git FOLDER_NAME
```

This will clone the master repo and the submodule repos as well.

Comment: I'm not trying to clone submodule. I had add the submodule to my repo already. I'm clone my repo in another computer.

Comment: Right, you want to have the content of your submodule folders filled. This is actually cloning those repos (a submodule is actually another git repo). If you prefer, you can replace _clone_ the submodules in my answer by _getting_ the content of those submodules