# git add submodule/path vs git submodule --init (submodule reference update)

Tags: git, git-submodules

What should I use to update the reference to the committed submodule to the parent project
so nect time I clone recursively the project It downloads the correct submodule commit?

Should I opt for `git submodule --init` or should I just `git add submodule/path` commit and push?

Note: my submodules are specific tags, not branches that have to be followed

Answer (score 2):

[`git submodule add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule/#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-add-bltbranchgt-f--force--nameltnamegt--referenceltrepositorygt--depthltdepthgt--ltrepositorygtltpathgt) is needed when you want to create a submodule entry in your repository, that is a [gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73834723/6309) (SHA1 [recorded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309) as a [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2227598/6309))

There is no `git submodule --init`, only [`git submodule init`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule/#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-init--ltpathgt82308203), which presupposes the submodule has already been added, and you want to initialize its `submodule.$name.url` setting in `.git/config`.

`git submodule update` will then update the submodule content of the ones declared in `.git/config` by `git submodule init`.
You can see an [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46582526/6309).