# Initialize Git submodule for configured commit only

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a Git repository with a very large submodule. In the cloned repository the submodule is not yet initialized. How to initialize/pull the submodule in a **snap-shot kind**, so it **only fetch**es the **single commit that is needed** (configured in the outer repository)?

PS: I don't want to clone freshly my repository, just want to "initialize" the submodule.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to \`git clone\` including submodules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796927/how-to-git-clone-including-submodules)