# Why there's no submodule directories when I clone git project with submodule?

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules

As stated in the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules#Cloning-a-Project-with-Submodules):

> When you receive such a project, you get the directories that contain submodules, but none of the files yet

I clone it with --recursive flag and git submodule init in it (?)

```
$ git clone --recursive git://path/to/repo.git
$ git submodule init
$ git submodule update
```

But I don't even get the directories.
The .gitmodule file is there.

.gitmodule content:

```
[submodule "Alamofire"]
path = Alamofire
url = https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git
```

I use git version 2.11.0

Comment: Did you do a [recursive git clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796927/how-to-git-clone-including-submodules) ?

Comment: Oh yeah, I did that. I updated the question.

Comment: Is the main repo public? If it is, can you share the URL?

Comment: It's private repo. I successfully clone the repo.

Comment: Its not automagic. If the project has submodule and your cloning for the first time then you need to do `git submodule init`. Check out the head of submodule after the init.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer updated

Comment: Ok, it's silly thing. I think my workmate didn't add the folder into git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's silly thing. My workmate seemed forget to add the submodule directory into git. The directory should add to the git.

> Although `DbConnector` is a subdirectory in your working directory, Git sees it as a submodule and doesn’t track its contents when you’re not in that directory. Instead, Git sees it as a particular commit from that repository.

[Documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)