# Clone submodule from GitHub

Tags: github, raspberry-pi3

I've recently just started using github, and I'm trying to figure out how to make this project work on my Raspberry Pi model 3.

This is the project that I'm trying to clone. 
https://github.com/dodgyrabbit/midi-light-py

Now my Adafruit_DotStar_Pi folder is empty. Is that where I'm supposed to add submodules for the project, and how would one do that?

/Alex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to \`git clone\` including submodules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796927/how-to-git-clone-including-submodules)

Comment: This solved my issue, Thanks mate!