# Git submodule project

Tags: git, git-submodules

My project has the following modules.

```
1. Controller
2. Models
3. Views
4. Interface
5. Settings
```

I want to have a `central repo` which is defined as `bare` and one `updater repo` and from the updater repo, will let others to clone their projects.

First I created a temp directory in the name of `modules` and copied my project folders and set up `git` for all the project folders.

```
.
├── modules
|   ├── controller/.git
|   └── models/.git
|   ├── views/.git
|   └── interface/.git
|   └── settings/.git
```

I then created a folder called `my_updater` and init git to this folder. 
Then I added the above `git` projects into as submodule of the updater folder.
for example,

`git submodule add ../module/controller controller
 git submodule add ../module/interface interface`

then in `my_updater` folder, I added the submodules and committed.

```
git commit -m "Initial Commit"
```

I setup my remote path of this `my_updater` folder as `central_repo` as follows.

```
git remote add origin ../central_repo
```

I tried to get all the projects in `my_updater` to  `my_workspace` folder as follows.

```
git clone ../my_updater my_workspace
```

Now when I looked into the my_workspace, all the folders of the submodule comes into that folder `my_workspace`. But all the contents of the submodules folders are empty. 
Why I didn't receive the submodule folders content here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to "git clone" including submodules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796927/how-to-git-clone-including-submodules)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+clone