# gitmodules doesn't work on existing project

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-bash

I want to clone submodules on existing project. I don't want to remove and re-clone the project.

The .gitmodules is below:

```
[submodule "submodulename"]
    active = .
    path = submodulename
    url = https://name-surname@bitbucket.org/xxx-team/submodulename.git
    branch = master
```

The git version is 2.12.2

I run these commands:

```
git pull --recurse-submodules
Already up-to-date.
```

But there is no folder called submodulename. How can I clone the submodules? How can I checkout a branch?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/3796927/5784831?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easy way to pull latest of all git submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030169/easy-way-to-pull-latest-of-all-git-submodules)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+update