# How to fix git submodule update --init --recursive not pulling CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: git, github

I have a project with several git submodules. I have `CMakeLists.txt` for each submodule and for the main project. When I `git clone` the main project, git pulls the main `CMakeLists.txt`. However when I do `git submodule update --init --recursive`, git pulls all the submodules, except the `CMakeLists.txt` in each submodule. Cloning the submodules invidually works properly. How do I fix this?

```
project/
  - CMakeLists.txt
  - src/
    - main.cpp
  - lib/
    - CMakeLists.txt
    - moduleA/
        -CMakeLists.txt
        - fooA.cpp
        - fooA.h
        - barA.cpp
        - barA.h
    - moduleB/
        - CMakeLists.txt
        - fooB.cpp
        - fooB.h
```

Comment: Have you tried to delete submodule folder and run the command again

Comment: @Raj I cloned the project in a different directory and then tried to update the submodules. But didn't work.

Comment: Also try to download when cloning : git clone --recurse-submodules ??

Comment: Okay, it worked! Somehow starting a new terminal, and then cloning did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While re-cloning everything will work, updating should have worked too.

Maybe those files were introduced in a more recent version of those submodules:

```
git submodule update --remote --recursive
```

That would fetch the latest of those submodules (`master` by default)