# Error build linphone flexisip server mac os

Tags: cmake, linphone

I am trying to build linphone flexisip server on my local laptop(Mac os)

This is all steps i have done

Install Required Dependencies:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
brew install git cmake
```

Clone Flexisip Repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/flexisip.git
```

Build Flexisip:
Navigate to the Flexisip directory and build the project using CMake.

```
cd flexisip
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

Then I have error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:47 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    ./linphone-sdk/bctoolbox/cmake/BcToolboxCMakeUtils.cmake


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:48 (bc_compute_full_version):
  Unknown CMake command "bc_compute_full_version".
```

Comment: Given project has **submodules**, so you need to tell git to clone submodules too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4438292/3440745