# Is there a setting in Git to automatically clone recursively?

Tags: git

If a Git repo has submodules, you have to use `git clone --recursive` to automatically check them out when you check out the main repo.  I always forget to add the `--recursive` so is there a setting that makes this the default behaviour for `git clone`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251940/retrospectively-add-recursive-to-a-git-repo

Answer (score 2):

You can always add git alias to execute any command you need.
Add the alias with all the desired flags and you use it from now on.

```
git config --global alias.clonesb "clone --recursive"
```

from this point on yo simply need to type `git clonesb` and it will execute the command with the falgs

Comment: Useless.  That would mean I'd have to remember to type "clonesb" instead of "clone" when the whole point is that I generally forget to type anything other than the normal "clone".  I also notice that Git ignores aliases that attempt to override normal Git commands, meaning there is no possible way to do this within Git.  Bugger.

Comment: Yeah, bash shell.  Not as good but at the moment the only way to do it.  I'm going to ask the git development list whether `git alias` can be changed to simply allow overriding builtin Git commands.  Not being able to seems like a ridiculous unnecessary limitation to me.