# Adding git submodule that contains another submodule?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I'm working on a project in one git repository (A) that is including another git repository (B), which in turn includes a third git repository (C).  In A, I added B via:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/blt04/sfDoctrine2Plugin.git plugins/sfDoctrine2Plugin
```

[Click here](https://github.com/blt04/sfDoctrine2Plugin/tree/master/lib/vendor), and you can see where B references C: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2

After doing my git submodule add, my `plugins/sfDoctrine2Plugin/lib/vendor/doctrine` folder (should contain C) is empty.  I tried doing a `git submodule update --recursive` as per [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535524/git-submodule-inside-of-a-submodule/1535541#1535541), but it still didn't import the files to that path.  I'm at a loss as to what to do here.

Comment: you could also re-clone the repository using "git clone --recursive <URL>"

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You need to do `git submodule update --init --recursive`. The problem here is the submodule C is never being initialized in the first place.

Comment: Wow, that did the trick. I don't know why git isn't smart enough to do that in the first place. Oh well, thanks!

Comment: git assumes that if you didn't init the submodule, it's because you don't want it. This is confusing to newcomers, but it can be extremely useful in cases where the submodule is optional.

Comment: It's always surprised me that you can't just do: git submodule add --recursive <git path>.