# Git detached head using Git Tower

Tags: git, git-tower

How should I set up a git submodule to prevent a detached head?

When I check out my project, it has a submodule and the submodule also has a submodule. Now I want someone else to be able to checkout the root and just build without errors, but because of the detached head - lots of source doesn't get checked out and the build fails.

So the main project checks out fine, the submodule is detached, which then means the sub-sub module doesn't get checked out!

Any help please?

Comment: Not getting your reasoning: why is detached HEAD in submodule preventing subsubmodule to be checked out?

And I don't know if detached HEAD in submodule can be prevented. AFAIK the main repo remembers only specific commit of submodules, not the "correct" branch the commit is meant to belong to.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's preventing it. Maybe it's a Git Tower thing. But I check out main, submodule is checked out (detached), submodule has 3 submodules itself - each of which don't get checked out.

Comment: I have no experience with GitTower, but is [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535524) related?

Comment: Possibly. I think it's doing a --recursive already. I'll look into it further.

Answer (score 1):

Using git command-line, this would be done with `git submodule update --recursive`, maybe also with the `--init` option if the submodules haven't been initialized. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168449/git-update-submodule-recursive)

The Tower client may or may not have recursive options in its GUI, or a git command line feature, so this answer might only be halfway helpful.

Comment: I'll have a look into that. I've just posed the same question to Git Tower support. Thanks