# Git multiple submodule references

Tags: git, dependencies, git-submodules

i'm quiet new to git and i don't know how to solve this specific problem in the best way. Hope you guys can offer me some good solutions. I searched the web but couldn't find an example like this which solved my issue. Maybe it's an design flaw? I just can't find a good solution.

I have the following projects:

- Common
- SqlApi: depends on specific Common version
- CoreLogic: depends on specific Common and SqlApi version
- Project A: depends on specific CoreLogic, SqlApi and Common version
- Project B: depends on specific CoreLogic and Common version

With submodules, the working directory of Project A looks like this:

```
Project A
    - Common(1)
    - SqlApi(1)
        + Common(2)
    - CoreLogic
        + Common(3)
        + SqlApi(2)
            * Common(4)
```

Is there an better way to get rid of the Common (2-4) and SqlApi (2) and let them all link to the same Common/SqlApi(1) version within one Project?

Maybe im just "routine-blinded" but i need some help to figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there an better way to get rid of the Common (2-4) and SqlApi (2)

Simple: in ProjectA, you only make a `git submodule update --init`, instead of [`git submodule update --init --recursive` (or `git clone --recursive`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1535541/6309).

That will give:

```
Project A
    - Common(1)
    - SqlApi(1)
    - CoreLogic
```

That means:

- `SqlAPI` and `CoreLogic` are able build based on variables (one variable for `Common` path, one variable for `SqlAPI` path,
- `Project A` has a build script which will set `SqlAPI` and `Common` path adequately.

That doesn't easily show that the versions might different/overlapping between the ones needs by `Project A` and the ones needed by one of the submodules.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
That means that git will checkout/update the commits which are referenced via the submodules of Project A for SqlApi and Common, am i right?

Comment: @s7urmi yes, Project1 records as [**gitlink**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309) ([special entries in the index](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309)) the SHA1 of those submodules.

Comment: k, that sounds good, i'll try immediately. Thanks for your help!