# git subtree of repository that uses git submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-subtree

Is it possible or recommended to add as a git subtree, a project that has .gitmodule dependencies(It was meant to be used with git submodule)?

If yes, is there a command to download recursively when adding git subtree?

This is different than the git submodule project nested in another git  submodule project because it's a git submodule project nested in a git subtree project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git submodule inside of a submodule (nested submodules)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535524/git-submodule-inside-of-a-submodule-nested-submodules)

Comment: No, I'm asking about a git submodule project nested in git subtree project.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-subtree%5D+submodules