# Adding a git submodule with a submodule sub-path

Tags: git

When configuring a git submodule, is it possible to reference a path of the submodule?

For example, I have a git repo (e.g. "SomeApp") with `src/app/SomeApp` directory in it. I want to add it to MyParent, which has `src/app/MyParent` directory in it. If I add a submodule with something like `git submodule add -b branch git/me/SomeApp src/app/SomeApp`, then SomeApp is cloned into the target path, and I end up with `src/app/SomeApp/src/app/SomeApp`.

Is it possible to map the submodule's `src/app/SomeApp` directly to MyParent's `src/app` directory, so that both SomeApp and MyParent are there without the extra subdir path on the submod?

Comment: Git only operates on entire repositories. You can't remap the layout of a repository like that (but you could add it at a different location and then use a symlink to create the hierarchy you want).

Comment: Was hoping there was some way of doing it with submodule. Thanks.

If you want to post your comment as a full answer, i can mark it as the solution here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git submodule inside of a submodule (nested submodules)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535524/git-submodule-inside-of-a-submodule-nested-submodules)

Comment: Areal - no. This is not for a submod in a submod (in a submod). This is a single submod, but only mapping in a sub-diretory of the single sub module to a different location.